# how to call a component inside another in a specific position in angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have two components in angular like the following :

mycomponent.component.html

```
<app-mycomponent2>
<p> this is a text </p>
</app-mycomponent2>
```

mycomponent2.component.html

```
<div class="bg-blue">
<!-- the code of first component should be added here-->
</div>
```

Now I don't know how to make my second component to call the code in a specific position because I'm going to use this code many times in my component and I want to avoid copy/paste instead use the structure I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "call the code," but it sounds like you're interested in "content projection." You use the `<ng-content>` tag to contain the content that will then be "projected" into your component for rendering. In your case, the `<p>this is a text</p>` content will be projected into the mycomponent2 via a `<ng-content>` tag.

Here's a pretty good example of projection:
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/content-projection/